# Face Tool in Photo Management softwares Linux

Tags: software-rec, images

Somehow, everywhere in the internet I see that the packages like F-spot, Shotwell and Kphotoalbum can detect faces in the photo library. But I have to say, after 1 day of round the clock research, I failed to find a suitable plugin or a tool. Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? How can I enable face recognition with any one of the above mentioned software or maybe some other photo management software that already has inbuilt face recognition feature. My goal is to get a open source package which can detect faces in my photo library.

Comment: I suggest to shorten this (very interesting) question to the important facts and move it to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/